# Not able to use Logback in WLS

Tags: java, xml, logback, weblogic12c

I need to use log-back in Webapplication project to be deployed in WLS where I have added log-back within WEB-INF classes folder.To pick the WEB-INF classes I need to add ,

`<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>`
in weblogic.xml but I cannot able to add because I am using 
`<prefer-application-resources>`

for some dependency which needs to pick from application not from WLS. Please suggest how to use log-back where  `<prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>`.

Answer (score 2):

Store your logbac.xml lets say at

```
$DOMAIN_HOME/application/logback.xml
```

add this into CLASSPATH in SETDOMAIN_ENV.sh or BAT.